# Nested JTabbedPane contents not rendering as expected

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am building a Java Swing application, and am trying to use nested JTabbedPane components in it, and am having mixed results.

In my top-level JFrame, I am able to successfully construct and load tabbed panes with JPanels. In the top level of the application, there are two sections, each assigned to a tab: General and Stream, both based on JPanels. Stream possesses its own JTabbedPane, as it is composed of three subordinate sections: Metadata, Input, and Instance, all also based on JPanels. All of the code written in the JFrame component works as expected. Tabs are initialized, JFrames are assigned to tabs, and it all displays correctly up to a point. Here is the code so far in my JFrame component:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class AppFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5294140238998011273L;
    private GeneralPanel generalPanel;
    private JTabbedPane appTabs;
    private JTabbedPane streamTabs;
    private MetadataPanel metadataPanel;
    private InputPanel inputPanel;

    public AppFrame() {

        super("Sourcecast");


        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
            .getImage(getClass()
            .getResource("/images/Apple-icon-64.png")));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        appTabs = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

        generalPanel = new GeneralPanel();
        appTabs.add("General", generalPanel);

        streamTabs = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

        metadataPanel = new MetadataPanel();
        streamTabs.add("Metadata", metadataPanel);

        inputPanel = new InputPanel();
        streamTabs.add("Input", inputPanel);

        appTabs.add(streamTabs, "Stream");

        add(appTabs);

        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        setSize(600, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Notice that I added the Input JPanel to the tabs, and its tab showed up. I put a JLabel in my Input JPanel to test it and it was visible. However, my Input JPanel is also loading a set of tabs, and those tabs are not visible when I run the app. Here is the Input JPanel:

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class InputPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7603090258673682140L;
    private JTabbedPane inputTabs;
    private StdinPcmPanel stdinPcmPanel;

    public InputPanel() {

        setLayout(null);

        inputTabs = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);       
        stdinPcmPanel = new StdinPcmPanel();

        inputTabs.add("StdinPCM", stdinPcmPanel);

        add(inputTabs);
    }
}
```

Below is one of the JPanels I am trying to load in the Input panel, and I have removed the other tabs in Input, just for simplicity:

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class StdinPcmPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -916207698149110923L;
    private JComboBox<CbOption> samplerate;
    private JComboBox<CbOption> channels;
    private JComboBox<CbOption> metadata;
    private JTextField metadatafilename;

    public StdinPcmPanel() {

        setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblSampleRate = new JLabel("Sample Rate");
        lblSampleRate.setBounds(12, 12, 230, 15);
        add(lblSampleRate);

        samplerate = new JComboBox<CbOption>();
        samplerate.addItem(new CbOption(48000, "48000 Hz (DAT)"));
        samplerate.addItem(new CbOption(44100, "44100 Hz (CD)"));
        samplerate.addItem(new CbOption(22050, "22500 Hz (FM)"));
        samplerate.addItem(new CbOption(16000, "16000 Hz"));
        samplerate.addItem(new CbOption(11025, "11025 Hz"));
        samplerate.addItem(new CbOption(8000, "8000 Hz"));
        samplerate.setSelectedIndex(1);
        samplerate.setBounds(12, 39, 156, 24);
        add(samplerate);

        JLabel lblChannels = new JLabel("Channels");
        lblChannels.setBounds(12, 75, 230, 15);
        add(lblChannels);

        channels = new JComboBox<CbOption>();
        channels.addItem(new CbOption(1, "Mono"));
        channels.addItem(new CbOption(2, "Stereo"));
        channels.setSelectedIndex(1);
        channels.setBounds(12, 102, 156, 24);
        add(channels);

        JLabel lblMetadata = new JLabel("Metadata");
        lblMetadata.setBounds(12, 138, 230, 15);
        add(lblMetadata);

        metadata = new JComboBox<CbOption>();
        metadata.addItem(new CbOption(0, "None"));
        metadata.addItem(new CbOption(1, "File"));
        metadata.setSelectedIndex(0);
        metadata.setBounds(12, 165, 156, 24);
        add(metadata);

        JLabel lblMetadataFile = new JLabel("Metadata File");
        lblMetadataFile.setBounds(12, 201, 230, 15);
        add(lblMetadataFile);

        metadatafilename = new JTextField();
        metadatafilename.setBounds(12, 228, 251, 24);
        add(metadatafilename);
        metadatafilename.setColumns(10);
    }
}
```

I realize that using all JTabbedPanes is not visually pleasing, and can be confusing. I actually intend to change that. However, I still need to know why this isn't working as expected. Below are two screen shots showing the top level tabs working ok, and then you see when Input is clicked, there is nothing visible.

[Imported JPanel shown in nested tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ1qd.png)

[Imported JPanel with its own JTabbedPane not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4xHr.png)

Comment: My first software question. It's obvious that I tried hard to do it right. I included code, screenshots, made a change to the code that is a matter of convention rather than a rule explicitly stated, and yet I still managed to get a down vote for it. I'm thinking the down side of gamification is that people will treat you like an obstacle that needs to be beaten in order to get to the next badge, privilege, or what ever. Douchebag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, my Input JPanel is also loading a set of tabs, and those tabs are not visible when I run the app.

Don't use a null layout. All panels should use an appropriate layout manager.

Probably use a `BorderLayout`, then the added tab will have access to all the space available to the input panel.

In the future (and if you need more help) post a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem when you post code. That is post minimal code that compiles and demonstrates the problem.

For example, we don't have access to your panel classes, so just use a JPanel to add to the tabbed pane.

Comment: When you say "don't use a null layout", what do you mean? My understanding is that it is equivalent to the Absolute Layout. Are you saying that the Absolute layout simply doesn't work? But it works in the other panels and tabs! Or do you mean it in a best practices way? I get that, and am struggling to build my first Swing application. Layout managers are another level of complexity that I intend to tackle once I have the pieces created and more or less fit together. BTW, I added one of the panels to be loaded in Input, and pared the code to just initialize and add that panel to the tabs.

Comment: Thanks, camickr. Worked like a charm. :) All I had to do was replace the `setLayout(null)` in Input with `setLayout(new BorderLayout())`.

Comment: `Layout managers are another level of complexity` - no they simplify the code as you have noticed because they will position components for you. Swing was designed to be used by layout managers. If you don't use a layout manager then you basically need to write the code manually (in order to get the GUI to work properly in many situations)  So learn how to use layout managers so you do coding properly from the beginning. The time you spent wondering why a null layout didn't work could have been used to learn more about a layout manager, so it is time well spent.